# I want to download the latest 150 files from S3 Spaces

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, aws, amazon-s3

I want to download the latest 150 files from S3 Spaces. I used this command

```
s3cmd get s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ /home/ankit -r | tail -n150
```

but it does not do what I want; instead, it starts downloading all the files

For example:
If I command: 
**INPUT**
`s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/`

**OUTPUT**

```
2020-04-30 20:04         0   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/
2020-04-30 20:04   1401551   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/501587671885rwk.jpg
2020-04-30 20:04    268417   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/501587676002xe2.jpg
2020-04-30 20:04    268417   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/501587677157ssj.jpg
2020-04-30 20:04    268417   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/501587747245hea.jpg
2020-05-01 05:23    399636   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg
```

And I want to download the only the last file (it is latest) that is:

```
2020-05-01 05:23    399636   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg
```

I can list the latest file but cannot download the latest file:
I listed through:

```
s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ | tail -n1
```

OUTPUT:
2020-05-01 05:23    399636

```
s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg
```

**SO, please tell me the command to download this latest file only?**

Comment: It _does_ work. It just doesn't do what you want it to do. What it does is to download all the files in `.../large/`, and list the last 150 of them.

Comment: So please tell me how can I download the last 150 files?

Comment: I want to download 150 (Latest) files from /large to my local - /home/ankit

Comment: What command can be used to list the file names and their sizes? Please add that to your question along with sample output

Comment: Please reply what command to use?

Comment: Please see I have added what you asked for?

Answer (score 1):

You've got all the pieces in place and what you need to do is to string them together.

This command provides the last file, which is the one you say you want, but we need to slice off the first part of the result

```
s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ | tail -n1
2020-05-01 05:23    399636   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg

s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ | sed -rn 's!^.*(s3://)!\1!p' | tail -n1
s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg
```

This command downloads a file

```
s3cmd get s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/some_file_or_other /home/ankit
```

So you put them together

```
file=$(s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ | sed -rn 's!^.*(s3://)!\1!p' | tail -n1)
s3cmd get "$file" /home/ankit
```

In another part of your question you talk about downloading multiple files, so here's an extension of this approach to get the last 150 files in `s3cmd ls` order:

```
s3cmd ls s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/ |
    tail -n150 |
    while read -r date time size s3path
    do
        s3cmd get "$s3path" /home/ankit
    done
```

Comment: SORRY! but what if I want to download 5 files?

Comment: Also when I `s3cmd get "$file" /home/ankit` it gives error: `Expecting S3 URI instead of '2020-05-01 05:23    399636   s3://obs/site1/uploads/large/87429599_1412258992269430_5992557431891165184_o.jpg'
`

Comment: I added: `| awk '{ print $4 }'` and now it is done! You are Great man! Thanks a lot

Comment: One more help? How Can I create symlinks for my directory `/public/uploads/*`  to be from a link  `abc.com/public/uploads/*`

Comment: I don't have the s3cmd tool, nor the S3 storage to test it on. You need to make sure that your question accurately reflects the output from these tools. I can only go on what you provide, so if you say (as you seem to) that `s3cmd ls directory/` returns a filename then that's what I will expect. If it returns metadata too, you need to make that clear.

Comment: One more help? How Can I create symlinks for my directory /public/uploads/* to be from a link abc.com/public/uploads/

Comment: @AnkitJaiSwal there you go, I've modified the answer to allow for the `ls -l` type output produced from `s3cmd ls`. I've used `sed` because the only constant in the line is going to be the `s3://` component (filenames could potentially contain spaces)

Comment: Hmmm.  Looks like you could use `cut -c30-` and `xargs` (since you’re already assuming that filenames don’t contain newlines).

Answer (score 0):

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

FILE="$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucket_name --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=  `'"$DATE"'`][].{Key: Key}' --output=text| grep file_name)"

aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/${FILE} .
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and add an explanation of the code?

Comment: Really!  This looks like a mess. It looks like you’re searching for file(s) that are modified in the future. The question asks you to use `s3cmd`; you’re using `aws s3` *`xxx yyy`*. What are `bucket_name` and `file_name`? You assume that the filename will not contain a space. The question asks for file(s) to be copied to `/home/ankit`; you’re ignoring that. And the question asks for the most recent 150 files. Your answer obviously doesn’t handle that; can it even be adapted to do so? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.